# Continuous-state Markov chain: Existence and uniqueness of stationary distribution

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, stochastic-analysis

On discrete space, we know that Markov chains are associated with a unique stationary distribution if all elements in the transition matrix $P$ are strictly positive. IIRC, an alternative sufficient condition is if $P^n$, $n\geq1$ has strictly positive elements.

I wonder if any such sufficient conditions exist to prove existence and potentially uniqueness of the stationary distribution underlying a continuous(/infinite)-state Markov chain.

Comment: A simple proof of existence of stationary distributions for the finite case is that to observe the set of all probability distributions on your state space is compact/convex (indeed a simplex).  Then for a transition matrix $A$, we look for a distribution $\mu$ solving $A\mu = \mu$.  But $A$ is continuous so by Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem we're done.  I'd imagine a similar result holds for the infinite dimensional version. For uniqueness, I'd look for conditions for which your analogue of $A$ is a contraction and use the Contraction Mapping theorem.

Comment: Irreducibility is the key ingredient for uniqueness in the discrete case (the conditions you state that $P^n$ has strictly positive entries for some $n$ imply irreducible, but not vice versa).  For general state space there is a definition of $\psi$-irreducible that may be useful.  You can google "psi irreducible."  When irreducibility fails, you can have two portions of hte state space that cannot be visited one from the other, and you can then have a probability distribution over one portion, and a distinct one over the other portion.